# What is Deep learning approach to count the number of Diamonds in an image?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, image-segmentation, vgg16

[image]I am working on a project which involves counting the number of diamonds in the provided image. I have a set of images and a VIA annotated .json file which has all the annotations. How do I proceed with this problem.

1. what approach to start i.e Object detection vs Instance segmentation ?
2. what models to choose from MaskRCNN,U-Net, etc (Please suggest) ?

Please guide.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say that go with Object Detection. Because you already have annoted images. And segmentation applied to locate objects and boundaries (lines, curves, etc.) in images. [image: Ref : ][1]]. **In Recent days EfficientDet Works very well in object detection. And for implementation look [here](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frwightman%2Fefficientdet-pytorch%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR1ECKTCWsEmPg0jZH81yY-MhwOgNNz-11l2H4_Loub888uVmLrBsac40h8&h=AT0dwg_g8hr_G5BLhXY_GERd5a30ye1pIwzCGw1rgSP0ZzybCVvsEpI3240IqvUhJULUIwLV_5iI_E98A_nnTsLVOmFXz48wZyvBXCW1NksvzfFDVxQd6fWptdYT&__tn__=R%5D-R&c%5B0%5D=AT0hughYtSn_jLtarzjPYX63CXfoRFu8DYEKT5c813S3CTQmynxfuM7kT9OArdb4YVLrrNAXVmcECIOfM3CFsBOhRCnRgfOe1LpGemHqXYZbjLLZT7mziLFJ7zJPkbtYhXiam7ndDtpqiN1-TDf0dR-ZONbk).** Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. Will object detection (EfficientDet) help if the project is later progressed towards identifying and clustering different types of diamonds in an image ? Will object detection work in identifying overlapping diamonds?  And how will instance segmentation be compared to object detection ?

Comment: Yes obviously if you detect the object then you can apply segmentation on them. Look at this paper (http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2595/endoCV2020_paper_id_11.pdf). In segmentation is detect the belonging pixels of the objects. Which can be done after the detection cause after finds the location we do segmentations. So that detection first is good for you because you have labelled images. Best of luck.

Comment: @uNIKx Are you clear about it?

Comment: Yes I got your point. Can you redirect me to any of the code implementation, it will be of great help to me. Thanks

Comment: Look at this code for details explanation (https://www.kaggle.com/shonenkov/training-efficientdet ). This code from Global Wheat Detection kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/global-wheat-detection/discussion/152368). Another implementation I already mentioned (https://github.com/rwightman/efficientdet-pytorch?fbclid=IwAR1ECKTCWsEmPg0jZH81yY-MhwOgNNz-11l2H4_Loub888uVmLrBsac40h8).  
Hope this help. If you find useful and it solves your problem upvote and mark inspire me a lot.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through mentioned code links. My organisation is preferring TF and Keras over PyTorch as TF will help in having the detection on edge, that is real time detection. How to workaround this as all the links are based on PyTorch ?

Comment: Yes, which I mentioned codes are based on PyTorch frameworks. For TensorFlow implementation, you follow this :  (https://github.com/Guillem96/efficientdet-tf)

Comment: And with the details explanation notebook from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/ravi02516/train-efficientdet-d0-d7-tensorflow) . Hope it helps you.  If you find any problem while implementation ping me anytime in my mail which I mentioned in my profile section. You may mark the Answer as accepted then. Best of luck .

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. I will try out the pointers and will mark your answer as Accepted for sure. I may also contact you on your email id for any further help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any time I will happy and appreciate then. Recently Kaggle launch a competition I feel similarly with your problem. Check this out (https://www.kaggle.com/c/hpa-single-cell-image-classification) . And you will also find me in Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/aifahim ) anytime. Best of luck .

Comment: If you follow the discussion thread and notebooks of this competition you will be benefited.

Comment: Discussion Thread (https://www.kaggle.com/c/hpa-single-cell-image-classification/discussion) and Notebooks thread (https://www.kaggle.com/c/hpa-single-cell-image-classification/notebooks). In Kaggle competitions you always find the state of art updated solutions.  And this competition is similar with your problems which means if you follow this , it will be cheery on the top for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for out of the box help. I will go through it and will let you know in case of any difficulty.